# I/O implications when using very wide rows in Cassandra

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm starting to work on a project using Cassandra (which I'm new to) and I'm working on developing a schema.  A question I have is what I/O implications are there for having a row with say millions of columns contained within it especially concerning writes?

To give clarity on what I'm trying to do, I essentially want to track what domain an IP belongs too.  One way I thought about doing this is to have a rowkeys like 'google.com' and each column within the row being an IP address belonging to said domain.  Someone told me that if your column is very wide and you change it, then it will create lots of I/O b/c it has to essentially re-write the entire row to disk at some point b/c the data is immutable.  Is this correct?  I thought that Cassandra would simply write the changed data and only the changed data to a commit log and memtable.  Then when the data is flushed and compaction takes place, it would merge the data into a new SSTable for the column family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wide rows are often used for time-series data, and shouldn't be a problem in general. Each row must fit on a single node (machine) though - see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraLimitations

One issue with your schema is that you would have to search all your domains (rows) to locate an IP, which will make lookup by IP very inefficient. If you do want to lookup by IP then rows keyed on IP in some way would be better; you might want both so you can look up in either direction.

You are correct about the commitlog/memtable->SSTable process, but see [this thread](http://cassandra-user-incubator-apache-org.3065146.n2.nabble.com/Fewer-wide-rows-vs-more-smaller-rows-td6651696.html) that mentions that compaction may be slower due to the `in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb` - but there have been some changes to compaction since that was written and it may be outdated info.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use playOrm which does wide rows for you and you can then just do S-SQL (scalable SQL).  You just have to partition the data properly to do S-SQL.  Generally partitions are by customer or by time, etc. etc. (you can do joins and everything as well within partitions).